# Is there any way to enable/disable a annotation by property in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some property file like:

**application.properties**

```
enable.test.controller=true
enable.cross.origin=false
```

I want to enable/disable some functions based on the profile. For example, I have a controller which only opening in specific environment:

```java
@Controller(enable=${enable.test.controller})
public class TestController() {

}
```

And I also want to enable/disable annotation `@CrossOrigin` property

```java
@Controller
@CrossOrigin(enable=${enable.cross.origin})
public class TestController2() {

}
```

Is there any way to make `@Annotation(enable=${property})` work?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can add `@ConditionalOnProperty` to your controller and specify the property based on which that controller's bean to be initialized or not.

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "enable.test.controller", havingValue = "true")
```

2. And for `@CrossOrigin`, if you want to add this annotation to single controller, you can specify the `origins` attribute in the annotation and specify the allowed origin URLs.

OR

You can create a global CORS configuration which can be easily turned off or on using a profile. for eg. `@Profile("CORS_enabled_profile")`

```java
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you! But I have another question: how could I enable/disable annotation like `@CrossOrigin(enable=${enable.cross.origin})` ?